# Custom cmdlet assemblies clashing with other cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, assemblies

I am trying to create a cmdlet in C# that uses the AWSSDK nuget package. What I am finding is that when I load my module in powershell when the [official AWS tools for powershell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) are loaded I am getting errors similar to this:

```
Get-AWSSessionToken : Method 'CredentialsFromAssumeRoleAuthentication' in type
'Amazon.SecurityToken.AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient' from assembly 'AWSSDK.SecurityToken, Version=3.3.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604' does not have an implementation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AWSSessionToken 646634
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AWSSessionToken], TypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException,Get_AWSSessionToken.GetAWSSessionTokenCmdlet
```

I think this is due to the 2 modules using different versions of the AWS assemblies which are overwriting each other on load, but I could be wrong.

I have tried to pack the AWS dlls into my assembly using [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) but that hasn't helped.

Below is my module manifest:

```
# Module manifest for module 'AWSSessionToken'
@{
RootModule = 'Get-AWSSessionToken.dll'
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
GUID = '6aff26a7-8573-43a1-919c-683dc2e32394'
Author = 'George Richardson'
CompanyName = 'foo'
Copyright = '(c) 2017 george.richardson. All rights reserved.'
Description = 'Allow generation of session tokens for AWS using MFA'
RequiredAssemblies = @('AWSSDK.Core.dll', 'AWSSDK.SecurityToken.dll')
}
```